# Are there different types of gravitational forces based on different types of masses ( inertial or relative etc)

Tags: forces, gravity, reference-frames, mass

There are different types of masses like inertial mass, passive gravitational mass, active gravitational mass, relative mass, et cetera. does Are there different types of gravitational forces that is exerted on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is only one type of gravitational force. The different types of mass are conceptually distinct and could *in theory* differ in value from one another. But every piece of experimental evidence that we have says that they are empirically the same to a very high degree of precision (at least one part in $10^{-12}$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass#Inertial_vs._gravitational_mass)).